# Apache2 and LD_PRELOAD libraries wrapping

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, unix, libraries, library

I'm trying to load a custom library on an Apache2 web server.
On Unix systems, I know it's possible to do it using the `LD_PRELOAD` variable.
I've configured `/etc/apache2/envvars` file to preload my library, appending an export `LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/mylibrary.so` , which usually works from command line operations (i.e. with curl), but when I try to restart the server, bash freezes to:

```
[....] Stopping web server: apache2
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: Typically you'll find an error message in Apache's error log file.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly by checking Apache error logs no error messages are shown...